# Socket stops receiving after X messages

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, http, tcp

I have a .NET `Socket` that listens to all TCP requests on the computer, and aggregates them into HTTP requests (where possible).

I have the following problem - 
When I access a site (for  example - `stackoverflow.com`) I see in WireShark that there are X (lets say - 12) TCP packets received from the site's host.
But in my code the Socket just stops receiving the messages before the end (after 10 messages)

I have no idea how to fix this, I hope it's something that is limiting the socket in his definition

Here is my code:

```
public void StartCapturing()
    {
        try
        {
            _chosenOutgoingAddress = UserChoosesIpCtrl();

            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw,
                                 ProtocolType.IP);
            _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(_chosenOutgoingAddress, 0));
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
                                    SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
            _socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, _bIn, _bOut);

            thrStartCapturing = new Thread(StartReceiving);
            thrStartCapturing.Name = "Capture Thread";
            thrStartCapturing.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: general exception handler
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The `StartCapturing` method will initiate the `Socket` and start the receiving thread with the `StartReceiving` method (as below0

```
private void StartReceiving()
    {
        while (!_stopCapturing)
        {
            int size = _socket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            int bytesReceived = _socket.Receive(_bBuffer,
                                                0, 
                                                _bBuffer.Length, 
                                                SocketFlags.None);

            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                _decPackagesReceived++;
                ConvertReceivedData(_bBuffer, bytesReceived);
            }
            Array.Clear(_bBuffer, 0, _bBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do know that TCP is a stream-based protocol and has no correlation to the number of packets on the wire, right?

Comment: of course, but this is probably not because of the TCP on the wires but because of the way .NET handles Sockets...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, so I'm posting here for anyone else who might need it in the future

The .NET Socket class has a property `ReceiveBufferSize` which determines what is the buffer that the Socket will allow.

My problem was that my code wasn't ASync, or fast enough to clean this buffer, so that the last TCP packets had no more buffer and were ignored.

Increasing the `ReceiveBufferSize` or make my code ASync (probably better :-)) will fix this.

Comment: You are of course correct, but in my case that's wasn't true.
It's because I didn't explain myself correctly - I am just sniffing tcp packets, I am not implementing a server that receives and answers tcp/ip